# Shopping Basket Notification

Tags: javascript, dom

I need a basket notification which pops up a red circle over the shopping basket with the number of items in the basket and to disappear if there are 0 items in the basket, much like the one in the below website.

http://www.howies.co.uk/beach-towel.html

Is it possible to do this without JQuery?

Here is my code so far.

```js
if($('#no_items').html() == 0){
    $(".circle").hide();
}
```

```css
.circle{
width:20px;
height:20px;
border-radius:50px;
font-size:12px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
background:#be1417;
 position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   left: 17px; 
}

#container {
    position: relative;    
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><div id="no_items" style="color:white">0</div></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QjEcx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can use innerHTML or innerText:

```
if(document.querySelector('#no_items').innerText === '0'){
    document.querySelector(".circle").style.display = 'none';
}
```

**update**

Or with pop-animation, as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/QjEcx/2/

Comment: @user2065466 Is your question answered? Then mark it as it is!